# changing textfield input to the date picked in a UIDatePicker (when value is changed)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uidatepicker

As you can understand from my question i can't get the UITextField (2 of them have an inputView as a UIDatePicker, 1 is normal) to change the text to the date picked in the UIDatePicker (a XIB file).
So far i managed to display the datePicker when the textfield is tapped (and remove it when the view is tapped, but I can't get the textField to change it's text to the date picked UIDatePicker.
here is my .m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#define kNIBname @"MyDatePickerView"


@interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTF;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myOtherTF;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *myDatePickerView;
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIDatePicker *MyDatePicker;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myTF,myOtherTF,MyDatePicker,myDatePickerView;
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self                                     action:@selector(dropPicker:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[self datePickerValueChanged:MyDatePicker];
MyDatePicker = [[myDatePickerView subviews] lastObject];
[MyDatePicker setDatePickerMode: UIDatePickerModeDate];
[MyDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[myTF setInputView:myDatePickerView];
[myOtherTF setInputView:myDatePickerView];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(IBAction)dropPicker:(id)sender{
[myDatePickerView removeFromSuperview];
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
- (void) loadDatePickerView{
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:kNIBname bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
NSArray *views = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
self.myDatePickerView = [views firstObject];
[myDatePickerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 318, 320, 162)];
[self.view addSubview:myDatePickerView];
}


-(IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender{
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:sender.locale];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
}
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
if(textField == myTF || textField == myOtherTF){
    [self loadDatePickerView];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setLocale:[MyDatePicker locale]];
    [df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [self datePickerValueChanged:MyDatePicker];
    [textField setText:[df stringFromDate:[MyDatePicker date]]];
    return NO;
} else {
    return YES;
}
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly, you are setting the date in the wrong method. `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` is called only once, before the editing of the textfield starts. What you want is to set the textField text in your `datePickerValueChanged` method, because that's the one that gets fired every time you pick a date.

Comment: But how will i know which textfield is active, i have other textfields which display a regular keyboard.